# How to remove a specific object from a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, oop, object

So I've go a list which stores Feeds objects which are constructed with a link and a category. Now I want to delete a given Feeds object that has a specific Link and category.

The declaration of my list:

```
public void addFeed(String link, String cat) {
    linkAcategory.Add(new feed(link, cat));
}
```

The add function:

```
public void addFeed(String link, String cat) {
    linkAcategory.Add(new feed(link, cat));
}
```

The delete function which is not working but shows what I'm trying to do:

```
public void removeFeed(String link, String cat) {
    linkAcategory.Remove(new feed(link,cat));
}
```

I hope I get any valuable help here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are link and cat both public properties of your Feed objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the T object has the link and cat properties:

```
linkAcategory.RemoveAll(x=>x.link==link && x.cat==cat);
```

Comment: I don't think that's how except works. I was under the impression that you pass an ienumerable collection to Except, and elements of that collection are excluded. Are you sure Except has an overload that works with lambda?

Comment: I can't get it to work like that. So I guess this doesn't work?

Comment: You're right about that, you need to implement an extension method for it to work like that, my bad, I was referring to it (implemented by my company's framework), RemoveAll should work as intended though. More about adding a lambda comparer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277760/can-i-use-linqs-except-with-a-lambda-expression-comparer

Answer (score 0):

The List object give you three ways to delete its elements.

1. Delete All Element by lambda condition
2. Delete specific element by index
3. Delete specific element by itself

*for example*:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>()
            {
                2,
                1,
                3,
                1
            };

 myList.Remove(1);// Delete 1-element from the index 1
 myList.RemoveAt(0);// Delete 2-element from the index 0
 myList.RemoveAll(x => x == 1);// Delete all elements that equal to 1
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way that your removeFeed method is written, your Feed class should override the Equals method. Something along the lines of:

```
    public class Feed
    {
        private string link;
        private string cat;

        …

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;

            var other = obj as Feed;
            if (other == null) return false;

            return other.link == this.link && other.cat == this.cat;
        }
    }
```

This is because the [Remove method of List uses the Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of its elements.

You might choose this approach over another when you want to keep some properties as private. This way the only thing the calling class has to know is the Equals method. It doesn't have to know the properties that determine equality.