# Compare two lists of object for new, changed, updated on a specific property

Tags: c#, list, object, compare, models

I've been trying and failing for a while to find a solution to compare to lists of objects based on a property of the objects. I've read other similar solutions but they were either not suitable (or I didn't understand the answer!).

Code is C#

I have a model that represents an image

```
public class AccommodationImageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool CoverImage { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }     
}
```

I have two lists of this model. One is the existing list, another is an updated list.  I need to compare the two lists to see which have been removed, updated or are new.

I don't need to compare the whole object, just compare them on their property Id.

```
List<AccommodationImageModel> masterList;
List<AccommodationImageModel> compareList;
```

#### New

If compareList contains any AccommodationImageModel with Id=0 then they are new because new entries do not have an Id assigned yet.

#### To be deleted

If masterList contains any AccommodationImageModel with Ids that are Not in compareList then they are to be deleted, because they have been removed from the compareList and should be removed from the masterList. Therefore I need a list of the ones that need to be deleted.

#### To be updated

If newList and masterList have Id's that are the same then they are to be updated. Therefore I need a list of the ones that share the same ID, so I can them update them. I'm not too concerned if these models are identical and don't need updating as there will only be a small number per list so it doesn't matter much if they get updated even if they haven't changed.

Each of the three results needs to be returned as a List of AccommodationImageModel so that I can then carry out the appropriate update, remove, add.

### Edit

I've added 3 test methods below with my chosen solution from ATM, showing its working implementation.

#### Test methods

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Test_Deleted_Image()
    {
        // set up the masterList
        List<AccommodationImageModel> masterList = new List<AccommodationImageModel>();
        masterList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 1 });
        masterList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 2 });

        // set up the compare list
        List<AccommodationImageModel> compareList = new List<AccommodationImageModel>();
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 1 });
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 3 });
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 0 });

        // get the deleted models
        List<AccommodationImageModel> result = masterList.Where(c => !compareList.Any(d => d.Id == c.Id)).ToList();

        // result should hold first model with id 2
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.FirstOrDefault().Id);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Added_Image()
    {
        // set up the masterList
        List<AccommodationImageModel> masterList = new List<AccommodationImageModel>();
        masterList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 1 });
        masterList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 2 });

        // set up the compare list
        List<AccommodationImageModel> compareList = new List<AccommodationImageModel>();
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 1 });
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 3 });
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 0 });

        // get the added models
        List<AccommodationImageModel> result = compareList.Where(c => c.Id == 0).ToList();

        // result should hold first model with id 0
        Assert.AreEqual(0, result.FirstOrDefault().Id);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Updated_Image()
    {
        // set up the masterList
        List<AccommodationImageModel> masterList = new List<AccommodationImageModel>();
        masterList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 1 });
        masterList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 2 });

        // set up the compare list
        List<AccommodationImageModel> compareList = new List<AccommodationImageModel>();
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 1 });
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 3 });
        compareList.Add(new AccommodationImageModel { Id = 0 });

        // get the updated models
        List<AccommodationImageModel> result = masterList.Where(c => compareList.Any(d => c.Id == d.Id)).ToList();

        // result should hold first model with id 1
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.FirstOrDefault().Id);
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simple Linq

New

```
List<AccommodationImageModel> toBeAdded = compareList.Where(c=>c.Id==0).ToList();
```

To be deleted

```
List<AccomodationImageModel> toBeDeleted = masterList.Where(c => !compareList.Any(d => c.Id == d.Id)).ToList();
```

To be updated

```
List<AccomodationImageModel> toBeUpdated = masterList.Where(c => compareList.Any(d => c.Id == d.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: That's the one :-)  This solution had the least amount of code to get the results. I've edited my original question and inserted test methods showing it's implementation

Comment: In terms of performance this will probably be slower than using Except which uses HashSet

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that two models with the same `Id` are considered the same model, you can write a `IEqualityComparer` like this:

```
public class AccommodationImageModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<AccommodationImageModel>
{
    public bool Equals(AccommodationImageModel x, AccommodationImageModel y)
    {
        if(x == null && y == null)
           return true;

        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(AccommodationImageModel model)
    {
        return model.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

You can then use Linq to get the lists that you want:

```
var comparer = new AccommodationImageModelComparer();

var newItems = compareList.Where (l => l.Id == 0).ToList();
var toBeDeleted = masterList.Except(compareList, comparer).ToList();
var toBeUpdated = masterList.Intersect(compareList, comparer).ToList();
```

The first one just filters the items with an `Id` of 0, which are conisdered new. The second query returns the items in the `masterList` which are not in the `compareList`. The last query returns the items which are in both lists. *This code compiles but is untested.*

Comment: I went for the '==' operator, since in my opinion `Equals` should have tighter criteria for equality than just the `Id` of an object, though in this instance it may be 'equally' valid XD

Comment: That's a valid approach as well. I had to use the `IEqualityComprarer` because Linq required it.

Comment: Combine this with this LambdaComparer and you're golden: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526553/151025

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to override the `==` operator in your`AccomodationImageModel` as such:

```
public static override bool operator ==(AccommodationImageModel a, AccommodationImageModel b)
{
    return a.Id == b.Id;
}
```

Then when comparing just check the master list against the comparer list and remove those in the master list that don't have an identical object in the comparer list:

```
List<AccomodationImageModel> rem = new List<AccomodationImageModel>;
List<AccomodationImageModel> newobj = new List<AccomodationImageModel>;
foreach(AccomodationImageModel a in compareList) {
          if(a.Id == 0) { // id == 0 => new item
                 newobj.Add(a); // add new item later
          } else {
                 // check those existing items as to whether they need to be updated or removed
                 bool match = false;
                 foreach(AccomodationImageModel b in masterList) {
                      if(a == b) match = true; // match found
                 }
                 if(!match) rem.Add(a); else Update(a); // will be removed or updated
          }
}
// now remove unmatched items
foreach(AccomodationImageModel a in rem) { masterList.Remove(a); }
foreach(AccomodationImageModel a in newobj) { AddNew(a); }
```

Note `Update(AccomodationImageModel a)` is your method to update a certain item and `AddNew(AccomodationImageModel a)` is your method of insterting a new item in the master list.

Also as you may have noteiced removing from and inserting to the master list should be done **after** you have looped the master list!

Answer (score 0):

```
    ///If image is not in list then add the image to the list

public void AddNew (List<AccomodationImageModel> masterList, AccomodationImageModel theImage)
{
    masterList.Add(theImage);
}

    /// If Image is in List then change listitem with new one

public void Update (List<AccomodationImageModel> masterList, int OldOnesID, AccomodationImageModel theNew)
{
    masterList[OldOnesID] = theNew;
}

    /// If Image should delete then removes the image from list

public void Delete (List<AccomodationImageModel> imgList, AccomodationImageModel theImageToDelete)
{
    masterList.Remove(theImageToDelete);
}


    /// this method checks the image state and do the work

public void CheckState (List<AccommodationImageModel> masterList, AccomodationImageModel theImage, bool deleteIt)
{


       for(int i = 0; i < masterList.Count; i++)
       {

         if (deleteIt)
         {
            Delete(masterList, theImage);
         }

         else
         {
           if(theImage.ID == 0)
           {
             AddNew(masterList, theImage);
           }

           if(masterList[i].ID == theImage.ID)
           {
             Update(masterList, i, theImage);
           }
       }
}
```

If you prefer use 2 lists as a master and Temporary list, then you can simply iterate your temporary list and each of templist item use CheckState method..

Hope this helps..