# remove duplicate rows between two tables using linq .net

Tags: .net

have two data tables as follows
How can i achieve this .

I have tried with Except ...but its eleiminating only '-1' row...i need qty 1 row also

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function. Do not have a ready made solution but you can try the same as described in this example of link:

```
Product[] fruits1 = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 },
                        new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };

Product[] fruits2 = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 } };

//Get all the elements from the first array
//except for the elements from the second array.

IEnumerable<Product> except =
    fruits1.Except(fruits2);

foreach (var product in except)
    Console.WriteLine(product.Name + " " + product.Code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var dtTwoIds = dtTwo.Select(element => new {element.ID}).Distinct();
var dtResult = dtOne.Where(element => dtTwoIds.All(ids => ids.ID != element.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Except, but you need to pass a custom IEqualityComparer that knows how to compare by ID.  Out of the box, you need to create a custom class, but many people write a lambda comparer to make it simpler:  [Can I use Linq's Except() with a lambda expression comparer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277760/can-i-use-linqs-except-with-a-lambda-expression-comparer).