# EF Core - Removing a related entity from collection navigation property does not update database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to understand this sentence:

> By default, for required relationships, a cascade delete behavior is configured and the child/dependent entity will be deleted from the database.

found in the "Removing relationships" paragraph in this Microsoft documentation of EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#removing-relationships

On a .Net Core API, with a model of blog and posts as follows

```
public class Blog
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

When I retrieve a blog by id through

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBlog([FromRoute] int id)
{
    return await context.Blog.Where(b => b.BlogId == id)
                             .Include(b => b.Posts).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

I receive in JSON

```
{
  "BlogId": 1,
  "Posts": [
    {
      "PostId": 1
    },
    {
      "PostId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

When I send back to the API the updated following JSON to be persisted in the database

```
{
  "BlogId": 1,
  "Posts": [
    {
      "PostId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

to

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutBlog([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Blog blog)
{
    this.context.Update(blog);
    await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return this.Ok();
}
```

Everything runs fine but no entries are modified.

As the relationship from a post to a blog is required and the related post is removed from the blog collection-of-posts property, **shouldn't post with PostId = 1 be deleted from the database?**

What really confuses me is that, as soon as I use a many-to-many relationship between blogs and posts, not changing anything else in the logic, the entry in table Blog_Post where PostId = 1 is actually deleted.

Comment: Is it possible that this issue is the root cause of it? [See GitHub issue Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/13331) The fix has been merged in release/2.2 branch and I'm using EFCore 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

`Update` merely associates the entity and marks all properties as modified. AFAIK it does not cascade down, or affect child collections.

As a general rule you should avoid passing entities to and from a web client. If you accept an entity to a web client, it is a simple matter to find the call passing the modified entity to the server, apply a breakpoint, and modify the contents using the debugger before resuming. If the server merely attaches the entity to a context and saves the changes, I can modify data in ways the application should not allow. It also involves sending more information to/from the client than is typically necessary.

Regarding the behaviour for deleting orphans, this applies when you modify the collections. You can find an example of detecting entities to add & remove and applying those changes in my response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906049/entity-framework-not-correctly-modifying-or-deleting-child-items/55053801#55053801) question.

Comment: Thank you for your input, however, in my experience and according to the documentation, `Update` performs "a recursive search of navigation properties", thus including child collections [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-2.1)
I understand that the code in my original post might not seem very secure but it is not production code, it is just about testing to what extent EF Core documentation is working or behaving as expected. I'll have a look at your other post

Comment: The huge difference I see with the question in your link is that the entities are correctly updated if you add, say, a "Name" to Blog and "Title" and "Content" to Post. The entities are well identified and values for these properties can be updated via this logic. I do not receive any exception or error message

Comment: That may be the case for entities that were constructed by a DbContext (still proxies). When you receive the entity back from the view in the controller argument it is merely a POCO object. Any tracking about related entities and such that may have been recorded will be lost. I don't believe Update could assess what changed without first having loaded the "real" entity from the database to compare against. The link example was just to demonstrate the add/remove association behavior against a loaded entity.

Comment: Yes, it can track them by checking PK values: "If a reachable entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the Modified state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the Added state."

Answer (score 0):

Enity Framework delete related entities from principle Entity to Dependent Entity. In your Case Principle is the Blog and Post is the dependent entity. By Deleting Blog related Posts should also be deleted.
You also need to decorate with Foreign key attribute, your class in that case will look like this.

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogForeignKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BlogForeignKey")]
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

You also need to define delete behaviour, you can do this by using Fluent API setting, Cascade will delete related entity, if you don’t want to delete related entity then use ClientSetNull , it will

```
model.Entity<Post>().HasOne(p => p.Blog).WithMany(b => b.Posts)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p. BlogForeignKey)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: I understand your point. How should I then understand the documentation when it says "You can remove a relationship by removing the related entity from a collection navigation" and "By default, for required relationships, a cascade delete behavior is configured", if I cannot remove the child from the collection and have to configure the delete behaviour myself? Moreover, I had a try at setting the cascade delete with the Fluent API, and it's not changing the result at this point

Comment: Yes by default cascade delete behavior is configured, when you delete parent object it deletes child object but remember your parent object must had populated child object, if child object is null it will not delete.